# Image Buttons that reveal Tabs

Tags: wordpress, tabs, wordpress-theming

I'm fairly new to wordpress and coding, though I have a background with HTML.
I'm looking to create something that should be rather simple. I want to create 3 circular image-buttons on a page. When I click them, I want them to reveal a related gallery. For example, you can see my testing site here:
http://centralia2050.dreamhosters.com/fanarttest/

As you can see I have 2 different tabs, but those were created by the theme, and I don't know how to create them on my own, let alone make them into interesting images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some programming knowledge like WordPress development, JavaScript/jQuery, PHP, CSS to develop such type of gallery on your own. You might want to start from here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/

If you need help in specific area, you can mention that so that I could help properly.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to edit the theme files if you're using a theme as you will have to change the way that the menu buttons look. Once you have found out where the styling for the menu is, you can edit it to look like circles e.g.

```css
#circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: .5s;
}

#circle:hover {
  opacity: .5;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div id="circle">
    <div>option 1</div>
  </div>
</a>
```

And then you can make it link to a page with a gallery on it which you can build like [this](https://codepen.io/JiiB/pen/xgdOjw)

I'm not entirely sure what you are looking for but hopefully this helps you in some way.